# Different layouts for different views in the same symfony application

Tags: templates, layout, symfony1

I have a symfony 1.4 project with the single application `frontend`. This application has the single module `book` with the single action `index`.

I have *two* templates for the index action: `indexSuccess.mobile.php` and `indexSuccess.html.php`. The action will set the format so as to call one or the other of these templates.

I want to use a different layout for each of these two templates: `layout.mobile.php` and `layout.html.php`. The file `apps/frontend/modules/book/config/view.yml` file is used to specify which layout to use as well as which CSS and JavaScript files are included in a layout.

Since there can only be one `view.yml` file per module, how do I configure `view.yml` so that `indexSuccess.mobile.php` uses `layout.mobile.php` and loads the appropriate CSS and JS files, while `indexSuccess.html.php` uses `layout.html.php` and loads *its* appropriate CSS and JS files?

I want to use layouts since I will eventually add many more actions/templates to this module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`setLayout()`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfAction#method_setlayout) method of your action to achieve this.
**UPDATE** for the css and js files, you can also use the action (call `sfWebResponse::addStylesheet()` and `sfWebResponse::addJavascript()`).
If you absolutely want to do all this from the `view.yml`, the best for you would be to change the template name (return a different suffix in your action)

Comment: This explains how to define a layout for a specific action but it does not answer my question as to how you can use the single file `view.yml` to configure more than one layout. Remember that `view.yml` contains configuration information for the layout such as what style-sheets to include, what JavaScript files to include, etc.

Comment: @rlandster: I think it is not possible to configure the layout on a per `sf_format` basis from the `view.yml`, hence my solution

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested, but seems like it does the trick:

```
<?php
    // in indexSuccess.mobile.php
    decorate_with('layout.mobile');
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be very late to answer this one, but thought it may help someone, due to their hard luck if they are asked to work on these legacy version such as symfony 1.4, like me.

You can able to specify the layout file per action. So the solution is to place the layout and my_layout in the `apps/frontend/templates` directory and define the layout configuration inside `apps/frontend/modules/book/config/view.yml` like following:

```
indexSuccess:
 layout: my_layout

mobileSuccess:
 layout: layout
```

For more information, Please check "Layout Configuration" in [this](https://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer) link